# How to convert HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument object to IHTMLDocument2 object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZ63.png) 
    Please Verify

> **using HtmlAgilityPack;
>       using mshtml;
>
> ```
>  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument obj = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
> IHTMLDocument2 obj1;
> obj = (IHTMLDocument2)obj1;**
> ```

Comment: I think you have done mistake in type cast just change this line obj = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)obj1;

Comment: Is that any possible reverse  casting

Comment: IHTMLDocument2 obj1= (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)obj;

Comment: Yes if the size of object is allow it

Comment: Can you please give a sample code for that

Comment: IHTMLDocument2 obj1=new IHTMLDocument2; obj1=(IHTMLDocument2)obj;

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZ63.png

Comment: Oh ! this is interface class you can not typecast or create an object of this class. you need to find some another way

Comment: ok ! is it any alternative!!?

Comment: my first question is why you want to this typecasting? yes, you can achieve by inheritance means you need to implement this interface method into your class.

Comment: Can you Give me a sample code  for that